# Arduino sprintf on char* not change value

Tags: arduino, printf

I want to concat a value to a char* variable (this value come from a sensor and I want make a GET with this value).. but, when I print the value on the Serial Monitar.. the variable not change.. only work the first time..

this the code..

```
int sensorValue=0;

void main(){
 Serial.Begin(9600);    
}

void loop(){

 char *hello = "GET /value=%i HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

 sprintf(hello, hello, sensorValue);
 sensorValue++;

}
```

Then, the Serial Monitor only print:

```
GET /0 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
GET /0 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
GET /0 HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n
```

.....

Comment: Using the same buffer as both the output and the format argument of sprintf is very dangerous. The string hello is initialized is using static memory, you cannot change it. Also, there must be a lot more code right? Can you include that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using Arduino Strings?
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringConstructors

Example:

```
void loop(){
    String prefixStr = "GET /value="; 
    String suffixStr = " HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.baidu.com\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

    String valueStr =  String(sensorValue); // integer to String conversion


    Serial.println(prefixStr + valueStr + suffixStr); // print it out the serial

    sensorValue++; // increment variable
}
```